# Azure VM -> Disaster Recovery Tab -> showing an Error Page

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, disaster-recovery

I am using an Standard Pay As You Go Subscription in Azure and while setting up the Virtual machine Disaster Recovery I am getting the Error Page as attached. Anyone else also faced this issue? or any idea about the fix please?

[image: Azure Disaster Recovery]

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? There were some outages in related services at this time, but nothing should have broken this blade. Also, what is your permission level for this VM / Subscription?

Comment: @TravisCragg_MSFT Seems you are correct. The issue automatically resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @TravisCragg in the comment section, it was due to outages at that time or it may be intermittent issue.

if you are still facing this issue, please submit a support ticket from help+support page in azure portal.